# how to store CGPoint in core data?

Tags: ipad, core-data, ios7.1, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to store the tapped location of view controller in core data. I am using `UITapGestureRecognizer` .

As user taps anywhere in the view,i want that location to get saved in core data.

How can i do this? Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: you can store a `CGPoint` as e.g. `NSString`. the conversion can be made via `CGPointFromString(...)` and `NSStringFromCGPoint(...)` static functions.

Comment: @holex thanks for reply, Can you please give an example with code.so, i can understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alteratively, rather than a string, you could create an Entity to represent a point with it's `x` and `y` values.

Comment: Ok Anorak,  you mean I should create a new entity for point position and another for points' detail, right?